# TikZ question for drawing the graph of the function 2000*1.01^x

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm using TikZ to draw some graphs, but I cannot get LateX to draw `2000*1.01^x`.

Here is the code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1, yscale=0.1]
\draw[very thick,red] (0,2000) -- (0,2150) node[anchor=south] { $y$};
\draw[xstep=1, ystep=5 , very thin, color=gray] (0,2000) grid (5,2150);
\draw[very thick, black, domain=0:5,samples=1000,variable=\x] plot ( \x , {2000*(1.01)^(\x)}) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: The compilation stops at parsing the first y-coordinate, and returns an error message saying `! Dimension too large.` If you scale down everything by a factor of say 10, then the compilation would go through.

Comment: Also, next time it would be nice if you could provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I tried to scale it, but it didnot work. I got a strait line not expentional line. Also, why can latex not work with numbers as 2000*1.01=2020?

Answer (score 9):

Straight line is normal because 1.01 doesn't quickly diverges from 1 when you take powers of it. You are operating in `cm` with Tikz, use `pgfplots` for it. It doesn't need any special care with big numbers. Here is a faster curve

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}% Package Version
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[grid=both]
\addplot{2000*(1.3)^x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If `pgfplots` is slower, you may use `gnuplot` along with `pgfplots`. I have  taken percusse's example and added `gnuplot` just to illustrate how easy it is. Also I have changed 2000 to 10000000 and used `domain=1:10`.

Compile this with `--shell-escape` or `--enable-write18` (`pdflatex --shell-escape filename`) and you should have `gnuplot` installed and it should be in system path.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}% Package Version
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[grid=both]
\addplot+[domain=0:10] gnuplot {10000000*(1.3)^x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A recommended solution with PSTricks just for fun.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=25pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\psset{yunit=\dimexpr1cm/2000\relax}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-6,0)(6,10000)
\psplot[plotpoints=25,algebraic,linecolor=blue]{-5}{5}{2000*1.3^x}
\psaxes[Dy=1000,linecolor=gray]{->}(0,0)(-6,0)(6,10000)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]